# WinAPI. Перенос строки в DrawText

Tags: c++, winapi

Есть окно, которое выводит конвертированную переменную int в строку, и все это повторяется в цикле (Должно быть 10 строк одной под другой). Код выглядит так:

```
RECT rc;
HDC dcc = GetDC(global::hwndGeneral);
GetClientRect(global::hwndGeneral, &rc);
SetBkMode(dcc, TRANSPARENT);
SetTextColor(dcc, RGB(0, 0, 255));

for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
{
    std::string x1 = std::to_string(math::vectorline[i].x1);
    std::string y1 = std::to_string(math::vectorline[i].y1);
    std::string x2 = std::to_string(math::vectorline[i].x2);
    std::string y2 = std::to_string(math::vectorline[i].y2);
    std::string n = std::to_string(i);
    std::string hd = n + " Line: A(" + x1 + "," + y1 + ") B(" + x2 + "," + y2 + ") ; ";


    TCHAR* b = 0;
    b = new TCHAR[hd.size() + 1];
    copy(hd.begin(), hd.end(), b);
    b[hd.size()] = 0;


    DrawText(dcc, (LPCWSTR)b, -1, &rc, DT_MODIFYSTRING | DT_PATH_ELLIPSIS);

    //DrawText(dcc, (LPCWSTR)intToCHAR(math::vectorline[0].x2), -1, &rc, DT_MODIFYSTRING | DT_PATH_ELLIPSIS);
}

ReleaseDC(global::hwndGeneral, dcc);
```

Но проблема в том что текст лепится один поверх другого, и соответственно в конце ничего не понятно. Добавление символа переноса строки в массив TCHAR* b (b[hd.size()] = '\n') тоже не дает результата. Какие есть методы переноса строки в функции DrawText()  ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Сначала сделайте одну длинную строку с переносами, затем отрисуйте ее все одним вызовом `DrawText`. Как вариант, можно модифицировать `rc`, добавляя отступ сверху на каждой итерации.

Куча промежуточных строк не нужны. Динамически выделять `b` (который кстати потом не освобождается) не следует, как не следует и кастовать `(LPCWSTR)b`